# "Select a site to pin" doesn't work for second tap in the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

"Edit site" page contains a "Select a site to pin" combobox with dropdown list of sites. Tapping on this combo for the second time doesn't open dropdown. Taping on the arrow (right hand side) works always fine. After such action dropdown starts working again.

> [image: video]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (172342203b663)